# Deselect selected row in Vaadin Grid

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

Can somebody give me a hint because I am stucked. And I haven't found the appropriate solution for my problem.

I have a `Grid`, with 1-3 rows. I click on the row -> the row is selected.

I want to have this row to be deselected after I click somewhere else (outside this row) but inside the grid.

Here is simple screenshot, to help you visialize it better.

[image]

What kind of listener should I use for this case? I have tried `ItemClickListener` -> haven't helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your grid in a separate layout and add `LayoutClickListener` to it:

```
gridLayout.addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutEvents.LayoutClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void layoutClick(LayoutEvents.LayoutClickEvent event) {
        if(grid.getSelectedRow() != null) {
            grid.deselectAll();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, this makes selection flicker when another component is selected, and also deselects when sorting is performed.

Answer (score 1):

```
gridLayout.asSingleSelect().addSelectionListener(e->{
    if(e.getFirstSelectedItem().isPresent()) {
          system.out.println("selected");
        }else {
         // when deselected make some actions here
            system.out.println("deSelected");
        }
});
```

**Selection:**
If you click on the same row of data for the first time , it will print ***selected*** ,since there are values present on what you clicked .

**Deselection:**
Now try to click on the same selected row for the second time , now it will go to deselection mode. since there are no values when you deselected.Now no need to click anywhere on the grid ,you can click on the same row of data for two times for the selection and deselection.

Comment: OP is trying to deselect the selected item *by clicking somewhere else than on the selected row*. They know that it gets deselected if you click on it again. this is not what they want

Comment: @KasparScherrer i agree with you , what if all the rows of the  grid is filled with data ? Clicking somewhere on the grid will select  other row(ofcourse the previous selected row will be deselected but the new row will be selected ), to deselect again clicked row ,  we need to click again somewhere on the Grid Unfortunately it will select row again  and it will be cont.... my idea would be selection and deselection should be done on the the same row inspite of clicking somewhere on the grid to deselect the presenet selected  row

Comment: @KasparScherrer he  also mentioned in the question that he wants to click inside the Grid to deselect the row. I took the scenario that, when the complete Grid is filled with data, deselection of one row will make selection of other row.